# Angular 2 es6 tutorial

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I want to learn angular 2 and I dont find any fully tutorial
I tried to search it on line but nothing seriously...

Does anyone know a complete guide to learn it seriously?
notice the es6 version.

Comment: yeah mostly the tutorial are in typescript, because angular team itself prefer angular2 with typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main differences between TypeScript and ES6 are:

- You can't use **strong typing**
- You can't use **decorators** for property and method parameters.

The second point is the "most" annoying since it allows you to configure things like dependency injection and link with DOM elements of the component template. Without the second, you can't leverage type checking...

I don't think that you'll find a comprehensive tutorial about how to use Angular2 with ES6. But only pieces of docs. So you need to guess how to "translate" things. At this level a document could help you at this level:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html#!#dependency-injection

Whereas the right column is ES5-specific, it could give you interesting hints to translate TypeScript code into ES6 one.

Here are samples:

- **Dependency injection**

  to translate this:

  ```
  constructor(@Inject('test') test, service:SomeService) {}
  ```

  you can see the `parameters` attribute in the "Injection with the @Inject decorator" section:

  ```
  constructor(test, service) {}

  get parameters() {
    return [['test', SomeService]];
  }
  ```
- **@ViewChildren**

  to translate this:

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class TestComp {
    @ViewChildren(HeroComponent)
    heroCmps:QueryList<HeroComponent>;
  }
  ```

  according to the "Query Decorators" section, you can use the `queries` entry of the `@Component` decorator:

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
    queries: {
      heroCmps: new ng.core.ViewChildren(
              HeroComponent)
  })
  export class TestComp {
  }
  ```

These articles could also interest you:

- https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-dependency-injection-in-es6-f5551a3d6bf#.dz7jz5ro9
- https://medium.com/@euphocat/angular2-router-in-es6-7-and-dependency-injection-b96944c3ba2e#.7xqvc5hlz

Comment: tanks a lot man! you realy help.  i think i learn TypeScript before to stay sharp and understand after that es6 better

Comment: https://medium.com/angular-2-with-es6/angular-2-with-es6-the-5-minute-quickstart-a9e4eb0bffcc

Comment: https://medium.com/@euphocat/angular2-router-in-es6-7-and-dependency-injection-b96944c3ba2e

Comment: https://github.com/timjacobi/angular2-education